# How to change or overwrite block reportlets created by ExtendedReports (reportlets)

Tags: contacts, civireport

I can't work out how to change the block/extended report once created, that I then use in the Contact Layout Editor, as overwriting it with the same name just made another block appear with the same name.

Comment: what are you seeing under Actions?

Comment: the usual: Create Report, Save a Copy, Print Report, Print to PDF, Export as CSV.

Comment: i just checked a site using Extended Report and I see the 'save' option but you do not list that. have you checked your permissions

Comment: I have full permissions as an administrator and only get Save a Copy option - but I am using the Create Report from Template and not editing the original copy - should the first copy I created using Create Report from Template be available for me to edit, and if so where?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should see all reports under 'all reports' & be able to go into it & edit it from there

[image: report list]

Comment: Brilliant - yes, that works, thanks!  It's a simple solution I know but I'm on a steep learning curv with civi and really enjoying it when things work :-)

Comment: It's always nice when things work :-)